# Facebook Graph Api call Returning Status 200 no content in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a call to facebook's graph api it is returning a status of 200 but the content is empty. When I make the exact same call in a browser it returns the data. Any ideas? Below is a code snippet of the call I am attempting to make:

```
        String appAccessToken = ((TestApplication)observer.getContext().getApplicationContext()).getAppAccessToken();
        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=school&type=place&access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode(appAccessToken, "UTF8") ;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```